# LARAVEL 8 404 NOT FOUND PAGE

Tags: php, laravel

THIS IS THE ROUTE
`Route::get('detail/{id}',[DirecteurController::class,'detail']);`

HERE THE FUNCTION

`function detail($id){ echo $id; }`

AND HERE IS THE BLADE PART

`@foreach ($liste as $item)

```
        <a href="detail/{{ $item->id}}" class="btn btn-info nav-icon fas fa-eye"></a>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-danger nav-icon fas  fa-user"></a>
        
      </td>
      @endforeach`
```

Comment: Php artisan cache:clear; php artisan route:clear;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Route::get('detail/{id}',[DirecteurController::class,'detail'])->name('directeur.details');
```

```
@foreach ($liste as $item)
    <a href="{{route('directeur.details',['id' => $item->id])}}" class="btn btn-info nav-icon fas fa-eye"></a>
     <a href="" class="btn btn-danger nav-icon fas  fa-user"></a>
     </td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: i maked previous change and i got this error 

Route [directeur.details] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\angelcare\resources\views\dashboards\directeur\rapport.blade.php)

whats problem ?

Comment: ```php artisan view:clear``` ```php artisan route:clear```  ```php artisan cache:clear``` run this command

Answer (score 0):

maybe because you are using a relative path without root, try to add "/" to the url

```
<a href="detail/{{ $item->id}}" class="btn btn-info nav-icon fas fa-eye"></a>
```

and you should using [named route](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#named-routes) instead